# ReactiveX JS and TypeScript - How to unsubscribe?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been attempting to implement a new rxjs `Observable` in an Angular 2 component using TypeScript. I have created a service, `MyService` that returns an observable in one of its methods, e.g.,

```
export class MyService {

    getMyObs(){
        return new Observable(observer => {
            observer.next(42);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my Angular 2 component I subscribe to this observable in OnInit, e.g.,

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
obs: any;

constructor(private myService: MyService){};    

    ngOnInit {
        this.obs = myService.getMyObs().subscribe(data => {
            // Do stuff here...
        });
    }    
}
```

The RxJs [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) talks about unsubscribing from your observable such that your observable knows to no longer emit messages to your observer. Therefore, I figured I should be unsubscribing from the observable when my component gets destroyed, something like

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
obs: any;

constructor(private myService: MyService){};    

    ngOnInit {
        this.obs = myService.getMyObs().subscribe(data => {
            // Do stuff here...
        });
    } 

    ngOnDestroy {
        this.obs.unsubscribe();
    }  
}
```

Whilst this makes sense to me, the typescript compiler throws (and indeed the application throws) saying there is no `unsubscribe` method. There appears to be no such method described in the type definition files. How do I correctly unsubscribe from an observable using TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add *unsubscribe* method to your `Observable`., [`Disposing Observable Executions`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#disposing-observable-executions)

```
return new Observable(observer => {
  observer.next(42);

  return () => {
    console.log('unsubscribe')
  }
});
```

Comment: Can we do it also in Angular 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the definition of the `unsubscribe` method in the `Subscription.d.ts` (class `Subscription`) of the Rxjs module.

As a matter of fact, you unsubscribe a subscription and not an observable.

Answer (score 1):

First create Subscription as follow.

```
private obs: Subscription = new Subscription();
```

Then assign to observable.

```
this.obs = myService.getMyObs().subscribe(data => {
       if(data !== null){
        this.obs.unsubscribe()
         }
    });
```